# How to display all the id_following

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, model

[image]

My Code :

```
        $this->db->join('followers','followers.id_follower = post.id_account','LEFT');             

        $id_account = $this->session->userdata('id');

        $where = ("followers.id_following=$id_account or post.id_account = $id_account");
        $this->db->where($where);
```

Please help me

Comment: What happens with this code? Did you fetch, and loop the fetch?

Comment: You need to use $this->db->select and  $this->db->get()

Comment: how to get id_following

Comment: how to get id_following in where?

Comment: The above code displays only id_following based session is not comprehensive :  $where = ("followers.id_following=$id_account or post.id_account = $id_account");

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

In you controller:

```
    // Set variables
    $page_data = array();
    $id_account = $this->session->userdata('id');

    // Get data
    $this->db->from('post');        
    $this->db->join('followers','followers.id_follower = post.id_account','LEFT');
    $this->db->where('id_following', $id_account);
    $this->db->or_where('id_account', $id_account);
    $page_data['followers'] = $this->db->get();

    // Load views
    $this->load->view('myview', $data);
```

In your view somewhere

```
    <?php if (!empty($followers)) {
        foreach ($followers as $item) { 
            echo $item['follower_id']; 
        }
    } ?>
```

You may want to use short forms of php in your view, but you get the idea.